# React Native :: build error | Dependency Incompatible

Tags: firebase, react-native, dependencies, build-error

I am new to react native and stuck with this dependency error. I am working on a project built by someone else and previously, it was working properly. The app uses 'react-native-text-detector' library. Not sure how can I fix this problem.

I get the following error when running on android.

In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[19.0.
2]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0 -> com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-co
mmon@[19.0.2], but play-services-vision-common version was 19.1.0.

The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
ifact with the issue.
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision@{strictly 24.1.0}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common@{strictly 19.1.0}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision@24.1.0
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-image-label@{strictly 18.0.4}
-- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision@{strictly 20.0.0}

---

I have tried :

- building with lower versions of gradle plugin & gms services
- using the googleServices.disableVersionCheck = true

Nothing has worked so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated. [The project gradle file is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWCSx.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your Gradle to the newest version. (6.6.1 on 23 Sep)